# AngularJS: How to sort or filter with two elements in option value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there may or may not be an easy workaround to this, but I have spent way too much time trying to figure this out.  How would I go about being able to display the query for the third option value which I want to display the filter of DB || CSLB from a json file?

```
<select ng-model="search.source">
   <option value="DB">DB</option>
   <option value="CSLB">CSLB</option>
   <option value="">DB & CSLB</option>
</select>
```

json looks like this.

```
"validated": false,
"matches": 10,
"renewed": 2005,
"exMod": 128,
"activeYear": 2003,
"effectiveDate": "10/0/2014",
"address": {
  "zip": 7806,
  "state": "Virgin Islands",
  "city": "Delco",
  "street": "402 Lawton Street"
},
"primaryName": "Lexicondo",
"source": "DB",
"ID": 9,
"_id": "55b5d21cc1389d427f90f9f4"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the code bellow help you to solve your needs, the only thing I used to do the sort is the filter method for arrays.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

The callback of the filter check if the source belongs to a value in the selectbox to group them, if not all the array will be showed(that's why the only thing the callback do is return a true).

```js
angular.module('TestApp', [])
  .controller('SearchController', function($scope) {
    this.source = 'All';

    this.items = [{
      name: 'One',
      src: 'DB'
    }, {
      name: 'Two',
      src: 'DB'
    }, {
      name: 'Three',
      src: 'CSLB'
    }, {
      name: 'Four',
      src: 'CSLB'
    }];

    this.applyFilter = function() {
      var _this = this;
      this.filteredItems = this.items.filter(function(value) {
        if (_this.source == 'All') return true;
        return value.src == _this.source;
      });
    };

    this.applyFilter();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="SearchController as search">
  <select ng-model="search.source" ng-change="search.applyFilter()">
    <option value="All">DB & CSLB</option>
    <option value="DB">DB</option>
    <option value="CSLB">CSLB</option>
  </select>
  <p>{{search.source}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in search.filteredItems">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```